# How to handle gap next to sink

Tags: vanity, bathroom

[image: Picture showing gap]

I have a house which was built in 1970 (so before the invention of the right-angle, I guess). Not a wall is straight.

When installing a new bathroom vanity, I have it aligned to the rear wall, but the side moves out 0.37" over 22".

What are some ways I can hide this transition? I did purchase the 'recommended' side-splash from Home Depot, but it's 1/4" too short in height, and 1/2" too short in length. The backsplash is 4" high, and the length needed for the side-splash is 22 1/2"

I thought of tile, but 0.37" is a lot of gap to make up.

Comment: Ah, yes - "recommended" by the finest in "we don't have what you need, but we'll sell you whatever we have."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps: Look at cove tile if you want to cover that gap. Alternatively, a 4" wide 1/2" thick stone threshold (on edge) should fit and cover the gap. White marble and black granite seem to be the common options for those.

Depending on the top material, you could also scribe the top (cutting it to match the wall)